# Trying to get Base Url in using Javascript(Mootools) in IE

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, mootools

What I'm trying to do is: Trying to get Href of BASE element using JavaScript(Mootools), It works in every browser except IE8.

It is throwing an error which is:  "Object doesn't support this property or method"

I don't have any Idea what is Happening Because it is working in every browser.

Here is my Code:

```
var asBaseUrl = document.head.getElement('base');
alert(asBaseUrl.get('href'));
```

I will greatly Appreciate if any one can help me. 
if you think question is not good please let me know in comments.
Thanks.

Comment: Hmm, are you sure there is something called `getElement`?

Comment: Opps I'm using Mootools. Sorry. I edit the question.

Comment: How about vanilla version? `var baseEl = document.head.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]; alert(baseEl && baseEl.href);` Should work in IE8.

Comment: Don't create global variables with the same name as element IDs. Don't create global variables at all.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko it is returning undefined.

Comment: `document.head` does not exist in IE8 and below, see here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.head#Browser_compatibility

Comment: Thanks @pomeh I have found the answer.

Comment: I know :) But now you have: 1) a working answer and 2) an explanation of why your code didn't work so next time you won't do the same mistake again :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `var asBaseUrl = document.getElement('base');`

Because document.head does not exist in IE8 and below, see here: 
It only Supports IE9 or IE9+
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.head#Browser_compatibility